# need help scripting website reboot

Tags: scripting, hosting, sql, website

I have a small website that crashes once or twice a week.

I have spoken to both the websites original designers, who has now retired and its host and both blame the other.

The website can be recovered by simply renaming a .dll file on the server which effectively reboots the website/application.

Is there a script or something that can be set to automatically rename a file at specific intervals?

Comment: This seems a horribly hackish way of solving the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with tombull89. Its horrid. But if you must, then it should be very simple to create a batch file that renames the DLL and then add it to the scheduled tasks lists.
Accessories->System Tools->Scheduled tasks.

Before you do this however, you should check the log files to see what is causing the problem. You might even be able to get an answer from serverfault!

Good luck! :D

Comment: Thanks for answering me and sorry it took so long to get back to you. I agree its not a great solution but from what ive been told the problem is a resource issue with the SQL database. creating the batch file and setting it to scheduled tasks would work fine on my computer but how would i make it affect a server hosted by someone else? the server belongs to fasthosts.co.uk as the website is part of my managers side projects and not actualy connected to the company i work for.

Comment: Then use the cron daemon on the remote webserver. An entry to restart the webservice at 0400 every morning would look something like this:

0 4 * * * /etc/init.d/apache2 restart